# Is the Australian accent similar to the cockney accent?

Tags: accent

I notice when Australians speak there's a familiar accent they speak that is cockney.

Comment: In order to avoid someone closing this question you may want to rephrase your description of the question as a question. Perhaps "...accent they speak. Is that cockney?" would do the job you were intending, however given your question is still not very constructive you may wish to make it broader by asking what influences the Australian accent has had on it, rather then asking if it is or isn't something specific.

Comment: Are you a Londoner? How familiar are you with the Cockney accent? Which Australian accent are you referring to—they're not all the same. And finally, where have  you heard Australians speaking? More detail please!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Despite what the person responding below says I think you would have to listen very carefully to distinguish a Western Australian from someone from Melbourne or Sydney. It always seems a very consistent accent to me, at least in urban areas.

Comment: @WS2 The Australian accents are not so much geographical as demographical, city vs country etc. But even so they are very similar.

Comment: I'm Australian and I've never heard an Australian Cockney accent. I would describe the most common Australian accent as being British without as much depth. Some are more British than others however - some people will say DAHNS for "dance" and others will say DANSE (long "A" vs. short "A").

Answer (score 4):

From my experience the Australian accent is not identical across the entire continent. The differences between the regions are not quite as obvious as you'd notice between regions in a country like the USA, but they certainly still exist.

I would characterise the Australian accent as being distinct in three regions: The East Coast, The West Coast and "The Regions", or Central/Rural Australia (this is of course excluding the very distinct accent of an English speaking Indigenous Australian). The Rural accent is what many within Australia may refer to as a "bogan" accent, that harsh, masculine accent epitiomised by movies like 'Crocodile Dundee'. The differences between the East and West are small but still substantive. The Western appears to have the same roots as the East but its softer, perhaps closer in many ways to its British origins. Within the East/West Coast accents however there is quite large variation, a product of Australian multiculturalism or their specific lived experiences I suspect. The variation in accents they could be exposed to in their formative years probably produces a less rigid outcome, and so it can sometimes be quite difficult to determine what heritage an Australian has or where they call home.

Its therefore very difficult to determine if the cockney accent has had a very heavy influence on any of the Australian accents, as where it might be very prominent in one individuals accent it may not be noticeable in any form in a different individuals accent. My intuition however somewhat leans towards saying it is both influenced and in most cases similar. It would make sense of course for many of the first Australian settlers to have had cockney accents, but in the centuries since the influence of the large number of Irish prisoners and immigrants, as well as the earlier Chinese immigrants prior and post the 'White Australia' Policy and the European immigrants after the World Wars on the accent, the base the distinct sound originates from would have shifted dramatically resulting in the cockney accent being less obvious.

I'm not sure there's an objective answer but my Australian intuition and experience says yes.

Comment: Speaking as a British person who has lived in Australia, and have read a little (not much) on the subject, it is clear that the Australian and New Zealand accents are derived from a south of England dialect - there is no hint of anything northern - though many northerners, Scots and Irish migrated to Australia. But it is not a south-west English accent, there is no hint of the rhotic R, as there is with American. However, it is by no means identical with Cockney. I have read that it has been identified most closely with Hertfordshire - a county slightly to the north-east of London.

Comment: @WS2 One small caveat: not all south-west English accents have a rhotic R. It's definitely prominent in (traditional) Bristolian, Somerset and Cornish accents, but many areas sound more 'RP-ish' these days. Those 'RP-ish' south-western accents are a better match for Australian than a northern English accent or an American accent, though possibly not as much as some south-eastern accents.

Comment: @Pharap Well, I live close to the Berkshire/Hampshire border, no more than 30 miles west of Heathrow Airport.  It has large numbers of recent incomers, and typically the Home Counties' range of  RP through other southern English accents predominate. But there are some "local" people left who have belonged to the area for generations - and even as far east as this, one does occasionally hear the rhotic R.