# Where does the General American accent originate?

Tags: accent

I’m referring to the usual mainstream American accent that Americans speak with. Where did it come from?

Comment: ***When Did Americans Lose Their British Accents?***
There are many, many evolving regional British and American accents, so the terms “British accent” and “American accent” are gross oversimplifications. http://mentalfloss.com/article/29761/when-did-americans-lose-their-british-accents

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/261626/70861

Comment: Are you the same user who has asked a load of questions about accents? You don't have to create a new profile every time you want to post a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [American English without an accent](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73732/american-english-without-an-accent)

Comment: 1. [How come asian americans never developed a american accent with a mixure of asian languages?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262281/how-come-asian-americans-never-developed-a-american-accent-with-a-mixure-of-asia); 2. [Is the Australian accent similar to the cockney accent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262264/is-the-australian-accent-similar-to-the-cockney-accent) and 3. [How did African Americans develop their own accent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262263/how-did-african-americans-develop-their-own-accent)

Comment: @Josh61 The end of your referenced article mentions **southeastern** England as a region with rhotic speakers. That’s wrong: it should be ***southwestern*** instead, given that [West Country English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_English#Phonology) is known for its rhoticism: “West Country accents are rhotic like most North American and Irish accents, meaning all "r"s in a word are pronounced, in contrast to non-rhotic accents like Received Pronunciation where "r" is only pronounced before vowels. Often, this /r/ is [...] lengthened at the ends of words.”

Comment: These are interpreting questions and answerable, but may take a book to answer even in its most simplified  form. I remember seeing on the web the notes to a class on English dialects that attempts to derive the sources. Note however that there are sources and then there is the independent development within the specific language community.

Comment: Please show some homework

Comment: Here's [a reasonable reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1sayfu/eli5_how_did_the_american_accent_develop_after/) discussing lots of issues. I don't think there is a good plain 'answer'.

Comment: @Josh61 one might just as well ask *When did the British develop their British accents?*  Certain elements in England, at least, clearly developed after Plymouth Rock.

Comment: +1 @Mari-Lou. OP: You are clearly interested in accents. Great. Try the library or Wikipedia. These are not specific, useful questions for EL&U.

Comment: [“General American doesn’t exist. He was demoted to private or sergeant a long, long time ago.”](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/is-there-a-place-in-america-where-people-speak-without-accents)

Answer (score 1):

I'm English and I occasionally mistake some Irish accents for American until I listen very carefully

> Irish Catholics
>
> According to the Dictionary of American History,[10] approximately
>   "50,000 to 100,000 Irishmen, over 75 percent of them Catholic, came to
>   United States in the 1600s, while 100,000 more Irish Catholics arrived
>   in the 1700s." Indentured servitude was an especially common way of
>   affording migration, and in the 1740s the Irish made up nine out of
>   ten indentured servants in some colonial regions.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_immigration_to_the_United_States

Comment: It would be interesting to investigate to what extent people of Irish heritage returning to Ireland from the US may have affected the Irish accent.

Comment: That's interesting, but it doesn't quite dovetail with my experience. Although I'm originally from Texas, I speak mostly with an SAE accent, and many Texans argue I must be from somewhere else. When I speak with people of Irish descent I distinctly hear the accent, though perhaps a bit mellowed from the Old Country. I presume that when I hear an accent that's a sign that its different from my own, which is to say my SAE is something distinct from third- or fourth-generation Irish. American English still varies regionally even though broadcast media slowly level the accents.